# Unable to install rodeo or spyder in my Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.5, spyder, rodeo

I'm trying to install an IDE for native ML/DA work but both of the top IDEs (spyder and rodeo) dont install on my system.
syder installed using `python3.5 -m pip install spyder`
but when I try to run spyder from Terminal using `spyder` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ImportError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 49, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 39, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

When I try to install `PySide`, I get:

```
only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
```

I currently use python3.5 for analysis and python2.7 for webdev.

So I uninstalled spyder using `python3.5 -m pip uninstall spyder` and try to install rodeo using pip as well as apt-get and neither work. I even tried `sudo dpkg -i install rodeo.deb` as explained [here](http://www.marsja.se/installing-rodeo-linux-ubuntu/) and got the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive install (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive rodeo.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install
 rodeo.deb
```

Trying to download rodeo from their website at yhat.com loads a blank page with a single line `Cannot GET /products/rodeo/downloads/linux64/null` and nothing happens - no download.

How do I install & use either one of these IDEs or something that would generally make ML/DA work easier?

And I haven't played with alternate builds of python such as anaconda, jupyter, ipython, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html#the-hard-way, the "No Qt bindings could be found" error for Spyder can be fixed by installing either PyQt5, which is recommended, or PyQt4 for Python 3. In Ubuntu, you can install PyQt5 by running:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

If you want to install PyQt4 instead, then run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```

Comment: I'd also like to say that PySide is not supported by Spyder anymore.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thanks; I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: We decided to drop it since Spyder 3.0 because PySide fails on us with very hard to debug errors. Besides it was hard for us to support three bindings at the same time (PyQt5, PyQt4 and PySide). Simpler applications (like `qtconsole`) can afford that luxury, but unfortunately not us :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am using anaconda. Using pip gave this error. So i did following

```
pip uninstall spyder
conda install spyder
```

Answer (score 0):

For installing Rodeo, the repo you're downloading is out of date.  Try running the commands below to install the latest version.  It should pickup your anaconda path automatically:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 33D40BC6
sudo add-apt-repository -u "deb http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com/ rodeo main"

#### install rodeo and run it
sudo apt-get -y install rodeo
/opt/Rodeo/rodeo
```